# Can't get API working under WSO2ESB 4.8.1

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I've added "API" through management console of WSO2ESB, very simple one:

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="getmessage" context="/newservices">
   <resource methods="GET" url-mapping="/getmessage">
      <inSequence>
         ....
         <log level="full"></log>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send></send>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

I see message logged in the end of inSequence due to log mediator, but can't get any response back. Error log is empty. Any idea how to receive it?

Besides, I noticed a couple of quite strange things:

1. Even if I specify wrong context in my request (/qwerty instead of
   /newservices) - such request is logged anyway, as if it was passing
   this inSequence
2. Setting "port" property for the "api" changes
   nothing, it does not even listen to the specified port

Any clue would be appreciated.

**UPD**

Following the hints provided by Jean-Michel, I found a combination of parameters to make it work finally:

```
<property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"></property>
<property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default"></property>
<property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"></property>
<property name="HTTP_SC" value="200" scope="axis2"></property>
```

I have no clear idea why, but only all of these used together forced API to return response body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside inSequence, you don't send anything to an endpoint and therefore, you don't receive any response : your outSequence is never executed. If you want to send back an ACK, you can set this property inside inSequence to send http satus code 202 :

```
<property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
```

When you send something to the ESB, if there is no service to handle the message, main sequence is executed by default and in main sequence, you will find `<log level="full">`

Comment: But what if I want to send some content prepared with inSequence, is it possible? The same way as it works for proxy services for example.

Comment: BTW, I would argue about logging in main sequence. Just because when I remove <log> from my inSequence - nothing is logged.

Comment: Of course, you can send some content prepared inside your api's inSequence, as you would do from a proxy service. Difference comes probably from the content-type that is something like text/xml when you send something to a proxy service and application/json when you call your api : you can adapt this content with property messageType.

Comment: Tried to play with messageType property (text/plain, application/soap+xml, etc.), but result is still the same. If nothing is sent to endpoint - it returns empty response (always 202 status code).  While I see the prepared  message logged in the end of inSequence. Nightmare(

Comment: May be you have some simple example of api that sends something back to client without calling endpoint?

Comment: Finally managed to make it work following your hints, thanks a lot! I'll update question with details.

Comment: you can add <header name="To" action="remove"/> to be sure that <send/> mediator will send back a response to the caller